# Why can't my iPad connect to any other machines on the same LAN?

Tags: ipad, network, wifi, google

I had an old iPad 2 lying around and decided to fire it up to test out a webpage I was making on my computer. Both devices are on the same LAN, connected using the same wifi ESSID and on the same subnet: `192.168.87.0/24`.

- Web Server IP: 192.168.87.22
- iPad IP: 192.168.87.23
- Laptop IP: 192.168.87.24

It's a Google Wifi with excellent signal strength.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a feature of Google Wifi :-| The missing detail above is that I was using the guest net feature of Google Wifi, since the password was easier to type ... The guest net feature has a security feature that no guest devices are able to see each other, meaning web dev and pinging devices is a no-go.